# Random GLU error 100155: tesselation coordinate too large

Tags: c#, opengl, glu

I have an `OpenGL` program (C#, using `PInvokes` to `opengl32.dll` and `glu32.dll)` that draws a rectangle using `tessellation` (I know I don't have too, this is for testing purposes) at 60 FPS.

Every now and then the drawing "flickers" and an error appears from the `tesselator`:

> "100155: tesselation coordinate too large".

I don't change the polygon. The 4 points of it are initialized once and are repeatedly being re-tesselated (again, for testing purposes only) except in some of the times it fails.

The test is run on Windows 7, and was tested with several display adapters and drivers, all with the same result.

Any ideas? Is it some faulty implementation in the Windows side? Am I doing something wrong (I know I didn't attach code so it's hard to tell, but is there a common pitfall for such an issue?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figures I was passing 2 value points rather than 3 value points to the GLU tesselator, and apparently it didn't like it :-)

Fixed that by recreating the array of points adding zeros as Z values.

Could be nice, though, if the tesselator would also support 2D.